# Using an XML Soap Service with a web proxy that has authentication (eBay Trading API)

Tags: authentication, soap, proxy, asmx, http-authentication

We have done some eBay integration work for a client, and they have introduced a challenge for us - they have a Proxy server that has a username and password for it.

We've been pointed in the direction of this article:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318140

This tells us how to use a proxy annonymously, but not with a username and password.

Towards the bottom of this article it does have some details on **Proxy servers that require NTLM authentication** but I can't see how to specify a username and password.

If it helps, I'm using C#.

Many thanks

Darren

Answer (score 0):

See "[Ways to Customize your ASMX Client Proxy](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2008/06/05/ways-to-customize-your-asmx-client-proxy/)". In particular, you want to set the [Proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.httpwebclientprotocol.proxy.aspx) property to point to a WebProxy instance. Configure it with the required credentials.